# Load AJAX Response Text into DIV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a PHP file which returns MySQL results based on post information from an AJAX request. I have it set to echo the information from the MySQL table. So, I want to know how to load that response text into a DIV with JQuery. If I look in Firebug, the response text is exactly what I expect, the results of the MySQL query, so I know PHP is doing its job.

Comment: I feel like your question is unfinished. Post some code?

Comment: Try posting some code, and tell us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

In its most simple form (as your question... ;))

```
$(<selector for the div>).load("url of the php-file");
```

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: thanks, but i need the immediate data provided by the php file. my code posts the order number to orderstatus.php, then I need it to load the response given by the php file (the order status). it will be a changing variable for every request.

Comment: I dunno. But I got it by using `$("#status").html(data);`

Comment: You already have the data. That wasn't that clear for me. Some code as an example would have made it easier to understand. And your comment made it more confusing^^

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, plain JavaScript? Maybe you can try this:

> ```
> var callback = function (response) {
>   var myDiv = document.getElementById("resultsDiv");
>   var textElem = document.createElement('pre');
>   textElem.innerHTML = response.text;
>   myDiv.appendChild(textElem);
> }
>
> Ajax.request(url, params, callback); // or whatever you use for your Ajax query
> ```

This basically would create a callback function. So when you make your ajax call (you didn't say how), pass the result to your callback function (so your javascript won't block the page while loading results).

A new <pre> element will be created, text inserted in it, and the element inserted in your (already provided) resultsDiv.

Text in a <pre> element is displayed in a fixed-width font like Courier and it preserves line breaks and spaces (in case you formated the text on the server, othervise you can create a span or div instead).

Comment: Now that I wrote the answer, I saw you mention jQuery. Should fix my example, probably will sometimes. But you got the solution, from your comments, so....